# How can I count total item in an object/record and count only the value = true

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var obj = (from r in db.Module_Completion
                  .Where(r => r.star_id == User.Identity.Name)
                 
                   select new 
                   {
                         r.adv_stud_success,
                         r.important_policies,
                         r.technology,
                         r.finances,
                         r.resources,
                         r.student_life,
                         r.next_steps
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

obj = {true, false, false , true,...};
This is only one record that I query from database by using Linq

The reason is I would like to display Finsished 2 of 7 , that is why I need to count items in a record.
Thank you in advance!

```
 public partial class Module_Completion
{
    public int module_completionId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string star_id { get; set; }

    public bool adv_stud_success { get; set; }

    public bool important_policies { get; set; }

    public bool technology { get; set; }

    public bool finances { get; set; }

    public bool resources { get; set; }

    public bool student_life { get; set; }

    public bool next_steps { get; set; }
}
```

After I can store numbers in variable, then I would like to display like this"Finished 2 of 7"

Comment: Did u mean u wanna see is there any record return in your query?  if yes, u can use var obj = (from r in db.Module_Completion .Where(r => r.star_id == User.Identity.Name).Any()  I guess you need to explain your question clearly before you get a vote down.

Comment: No @Yat Fei Leong , I do not want true or false. I would like the total number of item in a record and total number of value true in that same record, thank you

Comment: could you post your model and expected result?

Comment: @Yat Fei Leong, yes I did add the model and result I want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution involves 2 parts first. Create a ViewModel to get the number of completed object that associates with the class that goes:

```
public class ModuleCompletesVM
{
    public Module_Completion Module_Completion { get; set; }
    public int Completed { get

        {
            return (Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.stud_success) + 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.important_policies) + 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.technology) + 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.finances) +
                    Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.resources) + 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.next_steps) + 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Module_Completion.student_life));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this View Model would calculate the number of completed subject of each Module_Completion Class and then from your controller. You just need to do something like this

```
var model= from s in db.Module_Completion
                   select new ModuleCompletesVM
                   {
                       Module_Completion = s
                   };
```

You can also achieve this by creating a function in SQL database as well. Another piece of advice is that, do consider stop using underscrore in your data table and data field. Follow the latest convention, the next person who take over your code will appreciate that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and advice, I decided to go with your suggestion by adding ViewModel and YES I can store my total of true value of a specific record! For the database , property name that was created by database developer

Answer (score 1):

So Every `ModuleCompletion` contains several Boolean properties. If the value of such a property is true, you consider the item to be "finished".

You want to count the number of finished items in a ModuleCompletion.

The proper method would be to add a property to class ModuleCompletion.

```
public int FinishedCount => ...
```

If you can't do this, for instance because ModuleCompletion represents the columns of a table in a database, then consider to add an extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [Extension Methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

```
public static int CountFinished(this ModuleCompletion moduleCompletion)
{
    // TODO: implement
}
```

Usage would be:

```
ModuleCompletion x = ...
int finished = x.CountFinished();
```

This would work if your ModuleCompletion is in local process. However, if you want to do this database side (as queryable), this won't work: your database wouldn't know method CountFinished.

If you want to let the database do this, you could change your Select method:

```
int finishedCount = db.ModuleCompletions
    .Where(completion => completion.star_id == User.Identity.Name)
    .Select(completion => 
        completion.adv_stud_success ? 1 : 0 +
        completion.important_policies ? 1 : 0 +
        completion.technology : 1 : 0 +
        ...)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This looks rather ugly. Luckily we can create an extension method of `IQueryable<ModuleCompletion>`, such that you can use it as any other LINQ method:

```
public static IQueryable<int> ToFinishedCount(this IQueryable<ModuleCompletion> moduleCompletions)
{
    return moduleCompletions.Select(completion => 
        completion.adv_stud_success ? 1 : 0 +
        completion.important_policies ? 1 : 0 +
        completion.technology : 1 : 0 +
        ...);
}
```

This query can be translated into a language that your DBMS understands. Usage would be much easier to understand, much easier to reuse, unit test and modify:

```
int finishedCount = db.ModuleCompletions
    .Where(completion => completion.star_id == User.Identity.Name)
    .ToFinishedCount()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach where you can have the total finished as property. Here is an example

```
public partial class Module_Completion
{
    private bool _adv_stud_success;
    private bool _important_policies;
    private bool _technology;
    private bool _finances;
    private bool _resources;
    private bool _student_life;
    private bool _next_steps;

    public int module_completionId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string star_id { get; set; }

    public bool adv_stud_success
    {
        get { return _adv_stud_success; }
        set { 
            _adv_stud_success = value;
            if (_adv_stud_success)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool important_policies
    {
        get { return _important_policies; }
        set
        {
            _important_policies = value;
            if (_important_policies)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool technology
    {
        get { return _technology; }
        set
        {
            _technology = value;
            if (_technology)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool finances
    {
        get { return _finances; }
        set
        {
            _finances = value;
            if (_finances)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool resources
    {
        get { return _resources; }
        set
        {
            _resources = value;
            if (_resources)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool student_life
    {
        get { return _student_life; }
        set
        {
            _student_life = value;
            if (_student_life)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool next_steps
    {
        get { return _next_steps; }
        set
        {
            _next_steps = value;
            if (_next_steps)
            {
                total_finsihed += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /* This property is storing the finished count */
    /* using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; */
    [NotMapped]
    public int total_finsihed { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can do the following

```
var obj = (from r in db.Module_Completion
              .Where(r => r.star_id == User.Identity.Name)

                   select new
                   {
                       r.total_finsihed
                   }).FirstOrDefault();

/* if the technology, finance, resources are true then */
/* obj = {3}; */
```